# Can I add a checkbox to the uploaded image to make it the cover image? AntD

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, antd

I'm making a training project Trello clone with AntD. The card supports loading images (see screenshot). I'm using AntD image upload component and would like to add a checkbox to the preview to make the image the cover image of the card.

**Clarified:**

The output of image thumbnails is implemented by AntD and does not provide markup. I'm looking for ways to add some functionality to the image thumbnail output like the original Trello (see screenshot). I'm increasingly convinced that I can do this if I write my own thumbnail output, but I'd like to understand if this can be done using AntD.

Thank you for your help.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Modal, Form, Input, Upload, UploadFile, GetProp, UploadProps} from 'antd';
import {useAppDispatch} from "../../store/hooks";
import {editCard} from "../../store/slices/boardSlice";
import {setError} from "../../store/slices/errorSlice";
import {IEditFormValues} from "../../types/types";
import {MdOutlineModeEdit} from "react-icons/md";
import {PlusOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';
import classes from "./Card.module.css";

interface ICardProps {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    list: string;
    description?: string;
    images?: UploadFile[];
}

type FieldType = {
    title: string;
    description?: string;
    images?: UploadFile[];
};

type FileType = Parameters<GetProp<UploadProps, 'beforeUpload'>>[0];

type GetFileType = {
    file: UploadFile;
    fileList: UploadFile[];
}

const Card: React.FC<ICardProps> = ({id, title, description, list, images}) => {

    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<UploadFile[]>([])
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const [previewOpen, setPreviewOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [previewImage, setPreviewImage] = useState<string>('');
    const [previewTitle, setPreviewTitle] = useState<string>('');
    const [form] = Form.useForm();

    const showModal = (): void => {
        setIsModalOpen(true);
    };

    const handleCancel = (): void => {
        form.resetFields();
        setIsModalOpen(false);
    };

    const normFile = (e: GetFileType): UploadFile[]  => {
        if (Array.isArray(e)) {
            return e;
        }
        return e?.fileList;
    };

    const getBase64 = (file: FileType): Promise<string> =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
            reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
        });

    const handleCancelPreview = () => setPreviewOpen(false);

    const handlePreview = async (file: UploadFile): Promise<void> => {
        if (!file.url && !file.preview) {
            let tempProps = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(file));
            tempProps.preview = await getBase64(file.originFileObj as FileType);
            Object.preventExtensions(tempProps);
            setPreviewImage(tempProps.preview as string);
        } else {
            setPreviewImage(file.url || (file.preview as string));
        }
        setPreviewOpen(true);
        setPreviewTitle(file.name || file.url!.substring(file.url!.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
    };

    const handleFileChange: UploadProps['onChange'] = ({fileList}: {fileList: UploadFile[]}): void  => {
        setFileList(fileList);
    }

    const onFinish = async (values: IEditFormValues): Promise<void> => {
        let formData = new FormData()
        for (const file of fileList) {
            formData.append("file", file.originFileObj as Blob);
        }

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/image', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        })

        if (!response.ok) {
            dispatch(setError(`Upload error, ${response.statusText}`))
        } else {
            setIsModalOpen(false);
            dispatch(editCard({id, list, values}))
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.cardWrapper}>
            <div>{title}</div>
            <div className={classes.editCardIcon} onClick={showModal}><MdOutlineModeEdit /></div>

            <Modal title="Edit card" open={isModalOpen} onCancel={handleCancel} footer={null}>
                <Form
                    name="basic"
                    form={form}
                    labelCol={{span: 8}}
                    wrapperCol={{span: 16}}
                    className={classes.cardForm}
                    onFinish={onFinish}
                    autoComplete="off"
                >
                    <Form.Item<FieldType>
                        label="Title"
                        name="title"
                        rules={[{required: true, message: 'Please input Card Title'}]}
                        initialValue={title}
                    >
                        <Input/>
                    </Form.Item>

                    <Form.Item<FieldType>
                        label="Description"
                        name="description"
                        rules={[{message: 'Please input Card Description'}]}
                        initialValue={description}
                    >
                        <Input/>
                    </Form.Item>

                    <Form.Item<FieldType>
                        label="Images"
                        name="images"
                        valuePropName="fileList"
                        getValueFromEvent={normFile}
                    >
                        <Upload listType="picture-card"
                                defaultFileList={images}
                                onPreview={handlePreview}
                                onChange={handleFileChange}
                                beforeUpload={() => false}
                        >
                            <button className={classes.buttonUpload} type="button">
                                <PlusOutlined />
                                <div className={classes.buttonUploadText}>Upload</div>
                            </button>
                        </Upload>
                    </Form.Item>

                    <Form.Item wrapperCol={{offset: 8, span: 16}}>
                        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Save</Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>

                <Modal title={previewTitle} open={previewOpen} onCancel={handleCancelPreview} footer={null}>
                    <img alt={previewTitle} className={classes.imagePreview} src={previewImage}/>
                </Modal>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see no reason why you can't add a checkbox to the UI to toggle some "state", and I see no reason why you can't apply CSS to style the UI to what you desire. Can you [edit] to clarify in better detail what you are trying to do, what your expected result should be versus what it is currently with whatever you've tried? See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese, thanks for your attention, I've added some clarifications.

Comment: It still isn't clear what checkbox you are referring to or what you want the result to look like, but I'm gathering that you might be asking how to render an overlay over an element and render some controls in it like in the first image, the cat image with an overlay with what looks like an "eye" and "trashcan" icons?